# return absolute reference number

Tags: vba, excel

I am using follow code to find maximum value in a column. I need to know absolute reference number of where that value is found. I am hoping to use that absolute reference number in FOR loop and check what is in adjacent cells of where that value is found.

```
rng = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("H"))
```

I have tried using match but I am getting error 2042.

```
adrs = Application.Match(rng, Range("H:H"), 0)
```

Is there a way to find out where that maximum value resides?

Please note I am searching for time stamps so wrapping rng in `CLNG` is not an option.

Comment: Does `Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("H"))` return proper value?

Comment: Your above code works for me, is there any chance that some cells in column H contain errors?

Comment: @avb yes it does. I have used it at the beginning of FOR loop just before nested IFs and it always returns latest(max) value.

Comment: @CLR  No there are no errors. H is populated as FOR counter runs through the data set. Data set has no blanks or values with wrong format.

Comment: Can you post more of the code, to include the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or simply this?

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Columns("H").Find(Application.Max(Columns("H")))
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox rng.Address(0, 0)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim maxValue As Integer
'you set your area that you get mxaimum value from
Set rng = Range("H:H")
'determine the maximum value
maxValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
'select cell which contains found value
'(Find returns Range objects, so you can use it as you like)
rang.Find(maxValue).Select
```

Comment: There are more efficient ways of doing it, but since efficiency wasn't the case, I stuck to your methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are using the correct references.

For example, if the code is running off `Sheet1` and the data is in `Sheet2` then it is possible you will get errors. Trying this as an example I got the `Error 2042` for the `adrs` variable when the code and the data were on different `WorkSheets`.

Also, always remember to `Option Explicit` this will force you to delcare your variables.

Try the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindMaxValueAndReturnRowNum()

    Dim SomeWorkSheet As Worksheet
    'Here you can change the Sheet1 to that of you data sheet name
    Set SomeWorkSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim MaxNum As Long
    Dim adrs As Long

    'Notice the reference to where the code needs to evaluate
    'if there is no reference to a specific sheet then it will use the active sheet.
    MaxNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(SomeWorkSheet.Columns("H"))
    'adrs will return the row number
    adrs = Application.Match(MaxNum , SomeWorkSheet.Range("H:H"), 0)

End Sub
```